# optimize laravel eloquent built-in functions

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am optimizing a existing laravel project which has following code segment. this method is calling from another foreach. but this method gets almost 3 seconds to process a single round.is there anything that i can do to optimize following code.

```
public function getFavouriteForRace($raceId)
{
    $race = $this->raceRepository->find($raceId);

    $selections = $this->selectionRepository->getSelectionsForRace($raceId);

    //set product
    $products = new EloquentResourceCollection($race->products, 'Resources\ProductResource');
    $selections = $selections->map(function ($v) use ($products) {
        $v->setProducts($products);
        return $v;
    });

    $selections = $selections
        ->filter(function ($v) {
            return $v->selectionStatus == SelectionStatusRepositoryInterface::SELECTION_STATUS;
        })
        ->sortBy(function ($v) use ($race) {
            return $v->getBetTypePrice(BetTypeRepositoryInterface::TYPE_WIN, (bool)$race->fixed_odds_enabled) ? : 999999;
        });


    return $selections->first();
}
```